# Pedal circuit not working on 9 V battery or 9 V AC adapter

Tags: power, batteries, distortion, guitar-pedal

I built a simple [NPN fuzz pedal](http://beavisaudio.com/schematics/Dallas-fuzzface-npn-schematic.htm) (negative ground) and soldered it up on some perf board.  It works just as expected using my [power supply](https://tacklifetools.com/products/dc-power-supply-variable-switching-dc-regulated-power-supply-with-4-digital-lcd-display-reverse-polarity-high-temperature-protection-110v-115cm-alligator-leads-included?currency=USD&variant=40080368730270&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Gobiu_SSC_US_Api_All&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4uqM64rX8wIVqG1vBB1_LwP2EAQYAyABEgK2B_D_BwE) but when hooking up to a 9 V battery or a 9 V DC adapter the signal comes through clean without distortion (i.e. no effect.)  I'm a bit of a beginner and at wits' end so any suggestions or ideas are welcome.

This works and gives the distortion:

[image: This setup works.]

This does not:

[image: This does not.]

And this does not:

[image: Nor does this.]

Comment: Welcome to [electronics.se]! Please [edit] your question to include your schematics as images.

Comment: I assume you mean it's not clean on on battery or the dc adapter? A bit odd that it's not clean on battery.

Comment: I'm suspecting a grounding issue during assembly. Can you take high resolution images of your board from all angles?

Comment: If you have a multimeter, check that the 9V battery is still 9V while the fuzz is increased; same with all power sources.  I bet the battery/adapter voltage is dropping (while the power supply does not.)

Comment: @Passerby By clean, I mean there's no distortion it's just a clean sound on the amp.  As if the switch was on bypass but it's not.

Comment: @rdtsc I'm not exactly sure where I need to test.  From the tone pot (VR1) back to +9v?

Comment: @scott multimeter in voltage mode, one lead at the 9V in and the other at Gnd.

Comment: @Passerby That gives me 9v at all levels of both pots.

Comment: Even when you when have the input running? No fluctuation?

Comment: That’s correct.  A few mV is about it.

Comment: A simple fuzz box like this should also increase the output volume quite a bit, since it works by amplifying until clipping occurs.  If the volume level is the same, then something is built wrong.

Comment: Yes gain over 5000 is lots of gain

Comment: How much current is it pulling from your power supply, when it is "working"?

Comment: It should be 3/4 of  milliampere DC or 0.7V/ 1k pot

Comment: I checked again.  It’s pulling just above 3/4 mA like Tony said both when it’s working and not.

Comment: Okay so narrow down the possible problems. How are you connecting power? Clips vs dc jack?

Comment: @Passerby I have powered it all sorts of ways while trying to sort it out.  I have a DC jack wired up that disables the 9v battery when in use.  The effect doesn’t work when either the battery or the DC jack are used.  If I clip my PSU to the battery clip the effect works.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I did.  They're in the comments from your answer.

Comment: Solder a new 9v clip to the board bypassing the dc jack. Test with battery. And double check polarity? If you have the parts maybe try assembling a second board or testing on a breadboard.

Comment: I added a few pictures to help visualize.  The first picture with the clips attached to the battery clip gets me the effect.  Attaching a battery or using the jack do not.  I breadboarded it again and the same thing.  And before you ask, I've tried two other batteries. ;)  Also I verified polarity on the jack and that the batter disengages when a plugged into it.

Comment: It's hard to tell why different sources do not supply same voltage to the board. Is there an e-cap you can add to the board where power goes and then verify your voltage with each connection to see why it's different.  I'm assuming there are no other grounds like earth ground on your supply which may make a difference. + or -

Comment: There’s a ground port but iI’m not using it.  I’m assuming you mean an electrolytic capacitor by “e-cap.” Forgive my lack of knowledge.  I have the circuit breadboarded again and it’s behaving the same way.  Where would be the best place to add it and check voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Showing your link of the design you followed below:

[image]

Using any signal > 1mV will be distorted after 2 gain stages with variable gain over 5k from the C3 fully bypassing VR1 on max.  But since Q2 provides negative feedback on one polarity only, the gain is unidirectional resulting in narrow square pulses from this .

So the one reason, it does not work is perhaps the C3 came loose on the breadboard or VR1 is not tapped high fully.

R2/R3  attenuates the 8V pulses back down to low levels which can further be attenuated by the VR2 pot.

I would expect this should work well with low guitar signal levels.

**Another obvious reason is lack of 0V on -ve side of VR1//C3 with 1V >  V( C3) > 600mV . i.e. **missing ground from Vbat-****

Comment: Well the thing is, it distorts when hooked up to the PSU but when attached to a 9v battery (or 9v wall wart) there's no distortion, just a clean sound.

Comment: Hi @jonk, I linked to it in the original question.  It's a Tack Life MDC01.

Comment: @Scott Do you think there might be some "hum" residing in the power supply, then? If so, that signal would just get passed on straight to the output. (No gain, though.) Batteries are quiet.

Comment: Scott , did you match any of my voltages with no input? And fix Gnd?  This has lots of gain to clip even 500 uV rms

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I'm sorry I completely missed your update to the schematic.  I (think I correctly) took the measurements at those points.  

Your measurements, 9 - 8.7 - 1.4 - 2.4 - .6 - .7
Mine 
Working 9 - 8.8 - 1.3 - 4.3 - .62 - .46
Not Working 9 - 8.9 - 1.17 - 4 - .59 - .46

Comment: If it still works with the MDC01 supply across 9V socket, match the voltage to the battery 9V and use both for a test. Something is screwy

Comment: I’ve varied the voltage on the PSU from 8 to 11 and it still works.  Screwy indeed.

Comment: I'm wondering, not about voltage sensitivity, which is low with R ratios controlling this design,  but some other characteristic, (earth ground leakage?, noise)  that makes it fail as soon as the PS is disconnected leaving just the battery.  I see your DC voltage results indicate lower gain to me thus more linear or just below threshold for some odd reason.  Sometimes RF noise being amplified (AM Radio) superimposed will reduce the gain and ground loops can act as antenna.

Comment: Sometimes RF noise being amplified (AM Radio) superimposed will reduce the audio gain and ground loops can act as antenna.  but then you might hear faint AM radio too as this acts as a high gain soft rectifier

Comment: What is the  source frequency range ( bass or midrange) as the gain increases with f due to the two series caps and approx source desired input amplitude for fuzz gain threshold. When the input signal is slightly too low the gain is linear.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, It does actually carry a faint AM frequency when not on the PSU.  I’m out of town for a couple of days but I will follow up soon.

Comment: Then add 0.1 uF or more across Vbat on board. (if not done already , assume this necessary for any design)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a ground wire messed up in your circuit.

Disconnect the power supply from the circuit and unclip the battery.

Use an ohmmeter and measure from the negative terminal of the battery clip to the ground on the circuit.  It should have very low resistance (practically a short circuit.)

If there's no connection between the battery clip negative terminal and the circuit ground, try connecting the battery clip black wire directly to the circuit ground (remove your barrel jack.)  That should male it work from the battery.

---

What's going on is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxK8n2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The direct "-" connection between the power supply and the fuzz box is broken in your barrel jack.
- The "-" connection on the power supply is connected to the earth ground of the outlet.
- The guitar amplifier signal ground is tied to the signal ground inside the box somewhere.
- The signal ground from the fuzz box to the guitar amplifier connects the "-" (ground) of the fuzz box through earth wiring in the outlets and your house wiring to the "-" terminal of the power supply.

Graphically:

[image]

The hand drawn red line is the connection from the power supply "-" terminal to the ground of the fuzz box.

The AC adapter and the 9V battery don't have that earth connection, so the circuit doesn't get any power.

The culprit is the switching barrel jack - it isn't switching.  The ground wire from the barrel jack to the fuzz box is never connected to the ground of the barrel jack or the battery clip.

When there's no ground to the circuit, the signal just passes through. It'll lose some voltage going through, but it'll still be strong enough that it'll be more or less "normal" loud coming out of the guitar amplifier.

Comment: Thanks.  I’m out of town until Friday but I will certainly give this a look when I get back.